# Start WiFi AP services after boot

Tags: command-line, wireless, bash, embedded-system

I am new to shell programming in Linux. How should  I automatically turn my nanopi device into a WiFi Access Point after boot? What script should I write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write a script that brings up the AP.  An older tutorial that should basically work on debian systems is [here](https://thenewbieblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/wifi-hotspot-setup-on-ubuntu/). This gist is to install and configure `hostapd`.  This will get the AP started, but you'll probably want more than a link layer, like having the AP send data to a router that routes to the internet.  The tutorial covers this.

To get it to run on boot start the script in `/etc/rc.local`.